How to make my gRPC server stream interceptor close the stream if validation fails?
I am trying to implement a stream server interceptor in Go, and its job is to reject the RPC (and therefore close the stream) if the client didn't provide a certain header.
Based on the grpc-go interceptor example, it looks like the way to do this would be for the interceptor function to simply return an error.
I've implemented my interceptor nearly identical to the example, except for checking for my desired header of course, and return an error if the header is not present. However, even though my interceptor gets to that return statement, I don't see the resulting error/status logged on either the client or the server, and more importantly, the client receives no error as a result of invoking the RPC.
Am I missing something here? I previously had implemented the header check directly in the server handler function, and when the header wasn't present, the client did indeed see a stream error. I am trying to reproduce that same result with a proper interceptor.
Here is my interceptor implementation:
func ClientMetadataInterceptor(srv any, ss grpc.ServerStream, _ *grpc.StreamServerInfo, handler grpc.StreamHandler) error {
    md, ok := metadata.FromIncomingContext(ss.Context())
    if !ok {
        return status.Errorf(codes.InvalidArgument, "no incoming metadata in rpc context")
    }

    var headerValue string
    if len(md["required-header"]) > 0 {
        headerValue = md["required-header"][0]
    } else {
        return status.Error(codes.InvalidArgument, "missing required header")
    }

    md.Append("new-header-key", headerValue)
    ctx := metadata.NewIncomingContext(ss.Context(), md)

    // Call the handler to complete the normal execution of the RPC
    err := handler(srv, &wrappedStream{ss, ctx})

    return err
}


You're assumptions seem good to me. You don't state but I assume you've proof that the Interceptor is being invoked and the error path is being taken. To confirm "the client receives no error" means your e.g. _, err := stream.Recv() is succeeding? I will try to repro this.

I'm unable to repro your issue. I added a grpc.StreamInterceptor to a server and, when the client attempts to send invalid metadata, the client throws the error from the interceptor.

Hi @DazWilkin, yes I've run through the debugger and verified the interceptor is invoked, and the error path is taken.

To your point, I did find out that the error comes back to the client from the Recv() call, which surprised me. I would have expected the stream error to come back as a return value from where my client used the stub to invoke the RPC.

That said, I suppose as long as I get the error, that is better than nothing... but the problem this leaves me with now is that the error I get from Recv() is not io.EOF, which I think I'm supposed to use to understand that the stream is dead. How is my client supposed to know not to send any more messages to that stream? How does it know whether the received error was just for a particular message, or whether the whole stream needs to be recycled?
I'm new to the Go gRPC library, so would appreciate any insight. Thanks

The Recv method is what the client uses to invoke the RPC. I see your point. I think it shouldn't be io.EOF because that's not true. In this case, the client didn't send the required header, the server could possibly have more content to stream (but won't). The client should correct its behavior based on the returned error (code.InvalidArgument).

Ok. I guess this is just the way the Go library works. I did find this explanation on the Go Basics Tutorial:
"the client needs to check the error err returned from Recv() after each call. If nil, the stream is still good and it can continue reading; if it’s io.EOF then the message stream has ended; otherwise there must be an RPC error, which is passed over through err"
So best I can tell, there are 2 error scenarios from Recv()-- graceful stream shutdown (io.EOF), or RPC error scenario (generic err)
